# Subterms of a lambda application?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus

In a book on Type theory I am working through, there is a definition for subterms where the third case covers lambda abstractions and is given by
$$Sub((\lambda x. M)) = Sub(M) \cup \{(\lambda x. M)\}$$
but I would have thought it should be
$$Sub((\lambda x. M)) = Sub(M) \cup \{(\lambda x. M)\} \cup \{x\}.$$

Why isn't the set containing $x$ included, since $Sub(x)$ is given as $\{x\}$ in case 1 (basis)?

For example, in the identity function,
$$\lambda x. x,$$
the second $x$ is considered a subterm, but the first one (after $\lambda)$ is not. Just wondering why not.

Comment: Use–mention distinction.

Comment: Thank you Zhen. So in the case of the identify function example, I would guess that the second $x$ is a use, whereas the first is a mention, is that right?

Comment: Yes. The first occurrence names the variable being bound and is not itself a use of that variable.